# Rewrite rule to append a string in the url through htaccess file

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Currently my htaccess has code like

```
RewriteRule (.*)/$ /pagename.php?name=$1
```

Url structure is `http://www.abcd.com/brand_name/` and is working fine. Through htaccess I want to rewrite it as: `http://www.abcd.com/xyz-string/brand_name/`

How to do this?

Comment: So you want a prefix to be on every URL?  Like if I went to `/something/` you want it to redirect the browser to `/xyx/something`?  And is it any url that doesn't start with `/xyz/`?

Comment: url structures are abcd.com/xyz.php - I do not have any need to change those. But those who come from a specific pagename.php?name=blah - query string, I need to reset the url structure as abcd.com/string/blah/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `brand_name` what you want to get stored in the variable? Then try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^xyz-string/([A-Za-z_]+)/$ pagename.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

Note that you might have to change the flags depending on other rules in your .htaccess file. Also, with the above RegEx, `brand_name` can only consist of letters and underscores.

Comment: Did you change the php page's name in your original question? It now says `pagename.php?name=$1` when I believe it said `reviews_view.php?name=$1` earlier. Just checking if that might be the problem.

Comment: No that is absolutely fine.

Comment: Also: Are you testing it with a trailing slash? `http://www.abcd.com/xyz-string/brand_name/` If you leave that one off and just go to `http://www.abcd.com/xyz-string/brand_name`, the RewriteRule won't work.

Comment: yeah. TRailing slash is also there. "abcd.com/pagename.php?name=blah" - this url works. "abcd.com/blah/" - this also works. "abcd.com/fancystring/blah/" - how to make?

Comment: If `fancystring` always stays the same, you can just make it part of the first part of your RewriteRule, but it has to be spelled exactly like it will be spelled in the URL. You only need the RegEx for the "dynamic" part of the URL (the `blah` part, I'm assuming, can be different things). If I misunderstood your original question, please clarify! Is your .htaccess file sitting at root level btw.?

Comment: Htaccess is in the root level. "blah" is dynamic. "fancystring" is constant throughout. Already used rule in htaccess is "RewriteRule (.*)/$ /pagename.php?name=$1"

Comment: Please try it without that original RewriteRule and just the one I gave you. I just tested it on an own website and it should work. If you keep your previous rule too, `fancystring/blah` will be put into the variable `$1` and thus in your query `pagename.php?name=fancystring/blah`, which you probably don't want.

Comment: I am so sorry. last result was cached. your rule worked great. But came across another problem. All hyperlinks generated from the site as "abcd.com/blah/" -- through htaccess can we make it "abcd.com/fancystring/blah/". Other wise I have to go to each and every page and append "/fancystring/" in the anchor tag. Any hope on that?

Comment: Hmm, not sure if I understand what exactly you mean. Do you want to redirect all requests for `abcd.com/blah/` to `abcd.com/fancystring/blah/`? I'm not an expert on load times, but I think it's preferable to change the _links_ instead of redirecting all requests! Or is this an SEO issue? But yes, such a redirect should be possible.

Comment: Actually all this mess is to get rid of crawl errors. If it causes trouble in load time, then I have to edit all hyperlinks (not tough, just being lazy). If you get any solution then please post here. I am trying too. -- okay dont worry. I will change the links. Thanks a lot for the solution.

Comment: I'll try: add this rule right before the other one: `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z_]+)/$ fancystring/$1/` [NC,R] Edit: nope, sorry, not redirecting. Hold on... Edit2: The R flag for redirect was missing. (; Should work now!

Comment: Thanks a lot. will test and let you know.

Comment: Worked as a treat. [This is for you](http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQAH-Erd7kEqHHYTyCeWVUjnp3AgPEIVpwyKJEP9UHNV6MEqVhdPA). Thanks a lot.